# How do I uninstall a Rails plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to make multiple files uploading, and did this:

```
rails plugin install git://github.com/kpitn/swfupload.git
```

and now any `rails ...` command throws an error:

```
.../vendor/plugins/swfupload/lib/swfupload.rb:18: undefined method `middleware' for ActionController::Dispatcher:Class (NoMethodError)
```

that's why i can't even uninstall this plugin

That stops everything i do, i'm just lost

What is the solution? I couldn't find something explaining about `middleware` in rails 3 context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the vendor/plugins/swfupload directory.

Comment: yeap, that helped. And what about the `middleware` method? Is there a gem that provides it?

Comment: run **rake middleware** to see your middleware stack

Comment: M2_: If this resolved your issue, please mark the answer correct.

Comment: I'm sorry, i tried once, it told me to wait 8 minutes, then i forgot. Now i marked, Thank you!